# Gráfica en Php y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente problema en el cual estoy atorado. Quiero graficar unos valores que tengo en una tabla llamada "siniestros", los campos que me interesa usar son: "tienda" y "monto_robado". Estoy utilizando este código:

```
<?php
    include 'cn.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="Highcharts-7.0.2/code/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="Highcharts-7.0.2/code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="Highcharts-7.0.2/code/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>





<script type="text/javascript">

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'ASALTOS 2019'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{

            **<?php
            $sql=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM siniestros");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            ?>**
            name: **'<?php echo $row['tienda']; ?>',****
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
            <?php
            }
            ?>

        }, {
            name: 'PERRO',
            y: 50
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.85
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
            y: 4.67
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.18
        }, {
            name: 'Sogou Explorer',
            y: 1.64
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 1.6
        }, {
            name: 'QQ',
            y: 1.2
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 2.61
        }]
    }]
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Aquí el detalle está en que, cuando coloco el código de php NO me muestra nada en el navegador. Es la primera vez que realizo este proceso.

Comment: Carga la pagina donde esta el grafico q  no sale y  presiona Ctrl+U para ver el codigo fuente del script para saber como esta graficando el array de datos.

Comment: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bd\reportes_graficos\index.php</b> on line <b>61</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bd\reportes_graficos\index.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br /> aqui el problema

Comment: Continué con este tema, realice lo que me sugirieron que hiciera, ahora en la linea donde me mostraba el error. Me muestra los datos de la tabla, pero no me muestra la gráfica. Alguna sugerencia?